# Verificar se Java List possui atributos de objetos duplicados

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

Preciso de ajuda para criar uma lógica que verifique se determinada atributos de um objecto, armazenado em um `List<Object>`, existe mais de duas vezes.

Já tentei usar o `Set<E>` para verificar se é possível armazenar o dado, visto que não é permitido informações repetidas nele. Porém, o ID que necessito verificar se é repetido, repete em uma ordem não linear. Meu código para a tentativa é a seguinte:

```
public List<Object> processaListaAuxiliar(List<Object> listaDrem) {
    List<Object> listaAux = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Set<Object> hashSet = new HashSet<Object>();
    
    for (Object obj : listaDrem) {
        if(obj instanceof LinhaExcel) {
            
            if(!hashSet.add(((LinhaExcel) obj).getUgEmitente())) {
                System.out.println("-----");
            } else {
                System.out.println("TESTE");
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    return listaAux;
}
```

Comment: Você precisa saber quais estão duplicados ou simplesmente não mostrar mais duplicados?

Comment: preciso saber quais estão duplicados

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar uma stream para filtrar o atributo que voce quer verificar e imprimir cada um deles na lista.
Ex:

```
public class Teste{
        String nome;
        int idade;

        public Teste(String nome, int idade){
                this.nome = nome;
                this.idade = idade;
        }
}
```

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Teste2{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                Teste t1 = new Teste("a",1);
                Teste t2 = new Teste("b",2);
                Teste t3 = new Teste("a",2);

                List<Teste> lista = Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3);

                lista.stream().filter(t -> t.nome.equals("a")).forEach(System.out::println);

        }
}
```

Nesse caso ele vai imprimir cada objeto com o atributo que voce passou presente na lista.

Comment: Perdão, amigo, no projeto onde estou usamos uma versão do Java incompatível com essas funcionalidades... Mas é uma ótima solução

Comment: Entendi. Eu gosto muito de trabalhar os dados usando stream api.

Answer (score 0):

Já que nao tem como usar stream para filtrar os dados, voce podem fazer assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Teste{
    private String nome;
    private int id;

    public Teste(String nome, int id){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    static public List<Teste> pesquisarNome(List<Teste> l,String n){
        ArrayList<Teste> al = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Teste obj : l){
            if(obj.getNome().equals(n)){
                al.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return al;
    }

    static public List<Teste> pesquisarId(List<Teste> l,int i){
                ArrayList<Teste> al = new ArrayList<>();

                for(Teste obj : l){
                        if(obj.getId() == i){
                                al.add(obj);
                        }
                }
                return al;
        }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Nome: %s / Id: %d",getNome(),getId());
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Teste2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Teste t1 = new Teste("a",1);
        Teste t2 = new Teste("b",2);
        Teste t3 = new Teste("c",3);
        Teste t4 = new Teste("a",2);

        List<Teste> lista = Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3,t4);
        String nomePesquisa = "a";
        int idPesquisa = 2;

        List<Teste> repetidosNome = Teste.pesquisarNome(lista,nomePesquisa);
        List<Teste> repetidosId = Teste.pesquisarId(lista,idPesquisa);

        repetidosNome.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        repetidosId.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu criei dois metodo estaticos que vao te retornar as existencias valores do atributo que voce pesquisar. Ele nao vai te dizer se ha repeticoes, mas sim retornar a quantidade de casos em que um atributo recebe o mesmo valor.